# Compare and wishlist link doesn't work

Tags: magento-1, wishlist, compare

I need to add compare and wishlist link in to the `1column.phtml` file. I added this code in this page but nothing show!!!

```
app/design/frontend/default/celebrity/template/page/1column.phtml
```

**For compare link:**

```
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
            <?php if ($_compareUrl = $this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product)): ?>
                <span><a href="<?php echo $_compareUrl ?>" class="link-compare"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?></a></span>                
<?php endif; ?>
```

**For wishlist link:**

```
<?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $this->getAddToWishlistUrl($_product) ?>" class="link-wishlist"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It is because those functions do not exist on that block. The functions however just reference helpers so as long as the call to ->getProduct() is correct and returning a Mage_Catalog_Model_Product object you can do the following. Change...

```
$this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product)
```

to

```
Mage::helper('catalog/product_compare')->getAddUrl($_product)
```

and

```
$this->getAddToWishlistUrl($_product)
```

to

```
Mage::helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($_product)
```

**Edit**

Although i am still unsure as to why you are adding these to the 1column.phtml, by doing that you will need to change how you get the current product with;

```
$_product = Mage::registry('current_product');
if ($_product) {
    // put links in here
}
```

Magento out the box will give you add to compare / wishlist ability on listing and details pages.

Comment: I change these lines but when I clear the cache, the page is empty and nothing in it!

Comment: That is likely because there is no actual product available (the ->getProduct() is failing) again because no product has been set. How are you deciding what product you want to show these links for?

Comment: I want to add these links show in all products page that customer can do compare and add product to wishlist. And also I should add these links in `1column.phtml`.

Comment: I want these links work for all type of product. I just add these lines, what should I do that these links work?